# Draw an aircraft with polygon coordinates in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Could you please tell me, how can I draw a really simple aircraft with polygon-Coordinates in JavaFX? Here is some code to show you what the idea is:

```
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            100.0, -100.0,
            220.0, 11.0,
            290.0, 20.0,
            350.0, 200.0});
    pane.getChildren().add(polygon);
```

I don't know, which and how many coordinates are the best.

Comment: Finding the correct points to draw an aircraft has nothing to do with programming. If you are good at art, you can draw anything with graph paper. Programmatically, the sample code already produces a valid polygon, so there is no programmatic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't feel like an artist yourself you could also download one of the many SVG files from the net (for example this one: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airplane_silhouette.svg Just search for "airplane SVG") extract the path from the file and then use the JavaFX SVGPath class to display it. How to use the SVGPath is shown here
for example.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/2dshapes_svgpath.htm

Comment: Hi mipa, Thank you for your help. What do you mean by "extract the path"? How can do that? I can't see any path to use in SVGPath, which is shown in the Tutorial. There is a String variable which is initialized with -->   String path = "M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"; But I can't see any Path-Values in the Airplane silhouette.svg.

Comment: OK. I got it. Thank you for your Advice :-)